# Does sentry optimize duplicated breadcrumbs for different events?

Tags: performance, monitoring, log4j2, sentry

I have a Java application with log4j2. IFAIK all the logs are considered to be breadcrumbs. Let's say maxBreadcrumbs=100, my application logged two errors in a row.

Will Sentry log4j2 appender send two separate events with 100 Breadcrumbs each? 99 of the breadcrumbs will be identical for those two errors. Does Sentry log4j2 appender optimize it somehow?

Context: I'm configuring Sentry for the production environment and I have concerns about performance while using bimaxBreadcrumbs numbers